# Replace words in a sentence with words from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server and I want to create a `SELECT` query that replaces one or more words in a string with words used in another table. Like this:

```
SELECT [Message] from Table1
```

Returns:

```
Hello, my name is Thomas and i'm from Belium.
```

In `Table2` I have two columns

```
Original_Word-------Replace_Word
is------------------------is not
i'm-------------------------i am
```

So the select query I need must return this:

```
Hello, My name is not Thomas and i am from Belgium
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think that this is one of those rare cases where a cursor might be the best solution

Comment: How much words do you need to replace? always 2? or is it variable?

Comment: I'd guess you'll need a stored procedure here.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: version 2012,   the value in [Message] can contain 20 words to raplace or just 1.  this is variable

Answer (score 4):

You can use dynamic sql to build a nested replace:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = ''' '' + [Message] + '' ''';

SELECT @sql = 'REPLACE(' + @sql + ',''' + REPLACE(' '+Original_Word+' ','''','''''') + ''',''' + REPLACE(' '+Replace_Word+' ','''','''''') + ''')'
FROM Table2;

SET @sql = 'SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(' + @sql + ')) FROM Table1';

PRINT(@sql)
EXECUTE (@sql);
```

Comment: Though I think the idea is good, it has some issues with the single quote in `i'm` for instance. Also, it doesn't work with the idea of replacing *words* instead of just the letters. In this case you would replace `miss` with `mis nots`

Comment: Tab, nice work, I just edited your answer with the replace() to take care of the quotes in the strings.

Comment: This is good!  But it doesn't account for proper spacing.  If `OriginalWord` is "is" and the `ReplacementWord` is "is not" then a `Message` of "istanbul" becomes "is nottanbul".  You'd need to account for that in the table by padding every entry with a whitespace, or by padding the replace statement.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I see what you are doing now after reading the comments about single quotes in the replacement words.

Comment: I have edited to only perform the replacements on whole words.   A caviat is that if the original [Message] had leading or trailing spaces, they will end up getting trimmed, but I suspect that's better than the amount of ugliness that would be involved in keeping them.

Comment: This works for at most 32 words, because of the SQL Server nesting limit.

Comment: Doesn't work here,   can't this be done in a easy select

Comment: @ThomasDutoit What does "doesn't work" mean in your case?   Are you getting an error?    And no, this definitely cannot be done in an "easy select".

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval SQL.NET](http://eval-sql.net/)

Here is a solution by using C# code in T-SQL using Eval SQL.NET.

This solution is a little bit more complex then "EXECUTE" but at least you are safe from SQL Injection.
You can even improve the solution by using Regex.Replace instead.

Documentation: [Use regular expression in SQL](http://eval-sql.net/arithmetic-expressions)

```
DECLARE @tableMessage TABLE ( Msg VARCHAR(250) )

DECLARE @tableReplace TABLE
    (
      Original_Word VARCHAR(50) ,
      Replace_Word VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT  INTO @tableMessage
        ( Msg )
VALUES  ( 'Hello, my name is Thomas and i''m from Belium.' ),
        ( 'Another Template with is or is and i''m or not!' )


INSERT  INTO @tableReplace
        ( Original_Word, Replace_Word )
VALUES  ( 'is', 'is not' ),
        ( 'i''m', 'i am' )


DECLARE @sqlnet SQLNET = SQLNET::New('')
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'template'
DECLARE @pos VARCHAR(10) = '0';

-- CREATE the sql and set parameter value
SELECT  @sql = @sql + '.Replace(old_' + @pos + ', new_' + @pos + ')' ,
        @sqlnet = @sqlnet.ValueString('old_' + @pos, Original_Word)
                         .ValueString('new_' + @pos, Replace_Word) ,
        @pos = CAST(@pos AS INT) + 1
FROM    @tableReplace

-- SET the code to evaluate
-- template.Replace(old_0, new_0).Replace(old_1, new_1)
SET @sqlnet = @sqlnet.Code(@sql).Root();

-- Evaluate the code
SELECT  Msg ,
        @sqlnet.ValueString('template', Msg).EvalString()
FROM    @tableMessage AS A
```